# "Is it for when?" vs. "When is it for?"

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, questions

I always get confused which of the following is correct:

> 1. Is it for when?
> 2. When is it for?

Or are there further ways to ask for when something is needed.

The *it* in question is an enquiry, in case that matters. Please tell me whether these questions are grammatical.

Comment: Could you try to give us some context for the question you wish to ask?.

Comment: sir,there is not any context.I just used it and got confused whether i am using the right sentence or not?thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have extensively edited this question. The original indicates that you would benefit from our [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) site.

As regards your question it is option 2 which is correct. The first might just about be considered grammatical but sounds very awkward indeed.

Comment: Thank you sirs for your wonderful answers.I got that!Thanks

Comment: It would be ok to ask question for an enquiry,right? when is the date for? what is the date for your enquiry? what is the projected date for your event?Thanks

Comment: @NBR Can you give us a bit more information about these enquiries? It seems slightly odd to be asking when an enquiry is for. What sort of enquiries are they?

Comment: Dear sir,i felt odd to me as well and couldn't find out i am using the right form of the question or not,so i wanted to be sure on it.my question is if somebody asks me to check the availability of the Hall to book and i dont know the date.At that situation can i ask him like - when is it for? or is it for when?      is it correct to ask them this way? I think what is the date of your event? would sound much better,right?Any better ways of asking it?Thanks

Comment: 'What is the date of your event?' 'On which day do you want the hall?' 'What is the date and time for which you want to reserve the hall?' Or simply 'When is it for?' All these are fine. But you would definitely benefit from EL & L.

Answer (score 1):

Number 2 is the correct enquiry/inquiry. I assume your context involves asking someone when a project/assignment/application (or something else) is due or is needed. Here are some other ways of expressing your enquiry:

> - When is _________ due?
> - What is the deadline for __________?
> - When does ___________ need to be completed/submitted/finished?
> - When will _____________ be published/be made available/become public knowledge?
> - What is the projected completion date for ______________?
> - Do you know when _________________ is due?
> - What is your timeframe for _________________ ?

As you can see, there are numerous ways of asking someone "When is ___________ for? Take your pick, or use your own enquiry number 2.